# Is it possible to add two header files to a single swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, bridging-header

I have created two header files names commonclass.h and header.h in my Swift project. How to add those two file paths in the bridging header? I can add only one path to it and I need to add the second file path as well to bridging header.

Comment: include the second header file from the bridging header

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add both header paths but only one and that is **Bridging Header file only**.

You can add bridging header to your project as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/5546312) and then `#import` whatever header files you want to access from swift into this bridging header.